# Spark scala parameter in row.getDouble

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I got a very interesting bug when I try to transfer data frame to RDD in my class.

I construct a class named ROC and it looks like this:

```
class ROC(lines : DataFrame, x: Int, y: Int) {

    private val metrics: BinaryClassificationMetrics =
        new BinaryClassificationMetrics(
          lines.map(row => (row.getDouble(x), row.getDouble(y))))

}
```

It gives me an error

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
```

But when I type 0 and 1 in the getDouble() instead of passing parameter x and y, everything is fine.

```
              lines.map(row => (row.getDouble(0), row.getDouble(1))))
```

Although I have fixed this problem by adding select method before map, I'm so curious how this happened. Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `x` and `y` are `String`?

Answer (score 1):

Row.getDouble(index : Int) takes an integer index of row as input ,while x and y are defined as String. Your code should give a compile time error at row.getDouble(x) as x is a String. Chances are you are running some previously compiled  code.